# How to change API level when using buildozer?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I just finished my app and made a release version with buildozer and signed it but when I tried to upload my apk file to Google Play Console...It said that the API level of the app was 27 and it should be level 28. So how can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be edited in buildozer.spec file.
If you scroll down it's default to 27, change it to specification

Answer (score 0):

Find the line that says `android.api = 27` in your buildozer.spec file and change it to 28.